# XML schema's recursion of sequence of choices

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xmlschema

I have been stumped on this problem. I'm  trying to create a schema for xml with some complex recursion. I'll give an example:

```
<GenerationStack id="scattered_walls">
    <Noise type="perlin" gmin="0" gmax="1" size="10">
        <Noise type="binary_white" gmin="0" gmax="1" pmin="0.75" pmax="1">
            <Block id="wall_stone" pmin="0.75" pmax="1"/>
            <Block id="tile_stone" pmin="0" pmax="0.5"/>
        </Noise>
        <Block id="tile_stone" pmin="0" pmax="0.5"/>
    </Noise>
</GenerationStack>
```

The idea is for Noise elements to be able to contain any combination of Block and Noise elements.
I have found multiple things regarding refs and types but when trying those visual studio says:Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
`Warning The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:Noise' element is not declared.`
For this schema:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
    <element name="GenerationStack">
        <complexType>
            <sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
                <choice>
                    <element name="Noise">
                        <complexType>
                            <sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
                                <choice>
                                    <element ref="Noise"/> <!--element part shows the message.-->
                                    <element ref="Block"/> <!--element part shows the message but with block.-->
                                </choice>
                            </sequence>
                        </complexType>
                    </element>
                    <element name="Block">
                        <complexType>
                            <!--Still need attributes here-->
                        </complexType>
                    </element>
                </choice>
            </sequence>
            <attribute name="id" type="string"/>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

If anyone can put me on the right track that would be great. Thank you for reading my post.

Comment: Declare your elements at the top level (i.e. child of `xs:schema`) if you want to reference them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define a recursive schema you need to use `<element ref="..."/>`, and to use `<element ref="..."/>`, the element declaration it refers to must be global - that is, it must be a child of `<xs:schema>`.